# Detecting Eclipse (CDT) environment in macro

Tags: eclipse, macros, eclipse-cdt, stub

I'm compiling for an embedded target and my compiler understands some non-standard macros. I want to define some "stub" macros for the benefit of eclipse (so that it doesn't pester me with spurious warnings).

I want something like:

```
#ifdef ECLIPSE_ENVIRONMENT
void __WFI_STUB(void) {} 
#define __WFI __WFI_STUB
#endif
```

So that in my code (which compiles fine),

```
__WFI();
```

Eclipse won't freak out about an unresolved function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah.

```
#ifdef __CDT_PARSER__
// do stuff
#endif
```

Comment: See also this answer about `__CDT_PARSER__` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41388347/4561887.